# Attaching jQuery Event to AngularJS results

Tags: jquery, angularjs, events, repeat

How can I add a jQuery `click` event to a `li` which has been dynamically generated by AngularJS

The Angular code / database / filtering is working perfectly, I just want to make it so that when you click on one of the `li` it does something.

I'm new to Angular

HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit" data-name="{{data.customerName}}" class="myli">
               <strong>{{data.customerName}}</strong><br />
               {{data.addressLine1}}, {{data.city}}, {{data.state}}, {{data.postalCode}}, {{data.country}}<br />
               <code>{{data.creditLimit}}</code>
</li>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".myli").on("click", function(){
            var name = $(this).data("name");
            alert(name);
        });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would leverage the `ng-click` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick functionality on your `li`

```
<li ng-click="eventHandler(data)" ... class="myli">
```

and then in your controller

```
scope.eventHandler = function(data){
     alert(data.name);
}
```

You've now removed your jquery dependency and you can change all the element types, classes, and even what you want to call your data element in markup without ever having to change your code in the controller

Comment: As a general plan whenever you are using angular and think "I can do this with Jquery" DON'T.  Angular provides tools to do most of the UI manipulation and management that is historically done using JQuery. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background for tips